# Subcomponents for Encapsulation

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2, dagger

I've read the paragraph about [Dagger Subcomponents for Encapsulation](https://dagger.dev/subcomponents) 30 times at least, but I still can't wrap my head around what is going on here. What is the purpose of putting the Database implementation details into a subcomponent and then accessing it through the parent? What is to be gained from this? Is this something like a "module on steroids"? Will the Subcomponent still be used directly or does everything run through the ApplicationComponent?

Please note that I am aware of [this existing question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54575509/dagger-2-subcomponents-for-encapsulation).
But this one is not a how-to question, I am wondering about the logic and purpose of this structure and need someone to explain it in understandable terms.

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = DatabaseModule.class)
interface ApplicationComponent {
  Database database();
}

@Module(subcomponents = DatabaseComponent.class)
class DatabaseModule {
  @Provides
  @Singleton 
  Database provideDatabase(
      @NumberOfCores int numberOfCores,
      DatabaseComponent.Builder databaseComponentBuilder) {
    return databaseComponentBuilder
        .databaseImplModule(new DatabaseImplModule(numberOfCores / 2))
        .build()
        .database();
  }
}

@Module
class DatabaseImplModule {
  DatabaseImplModule(int concurrencyLevel) {}
  @Provides DatabaseConnectionPool     provideDatabaseConnectionPool() {}
  @Provides DatabaseSchema provideDatabaseSchema() {}
}

@Subcomponent(modules = DatabaseImplModule.class)
interface DatabaseComponent {
  @PrivateToDatabase Database database();
}
```